# How to make slideshow using Bitmap functionality in android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, slideshow

Hi guys I have tired using bitmap functionality and i can fetch the images but i can display them in only grid view. i want to display them in image view with slideshow. pls let me know if i can do this with bitmap. here is code for my app it is in a `ScrollView`.

```
package com.example.sdcardimagessync;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    /**
     * Grid view holding the images.
     */
    private GridView sdcardImages;
    /**
     * Image adapter for the grid view.
     */
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    /**
     * Display used for getting the width of the screen.
     */
    private Display display;

    /**
     * Creates the content view, sets up the grid, the adapter, and the click
     * listener.
     * 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Request progress bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                .getDefaultDisplay();

        setupViews();
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        loadImages();
    }

    /**
     * Free up bitmap related resources.
     */
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        final GridView grid = sdcardImages;
        final int count = grid.getChildCount();
        ImageView v = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            v = (ImageView) grid.getChildAt(i);
            ((BitmapDrawable) v.getDrawable()).setCallback(null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Setup the grid view.
     */
    private void setupViews() {
        sdcardImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.GridView1);
        sdcardImages.setNumColumns(display.getWidth() / 1000);
        sdcardImages.setClipToPadding(false);
        sdcardImages.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        sdcardImages.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    }

    /**
     * Load images.
     */
    private void loadImages() {
        final Object data = getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        if (data == null) {
            new LoadImagesFromSDCard().execute();
        } else {
            final LoadedImage[] photos = (LoadedImage[]) data;
            if (photos.length == 0) {
                new LoadImagesFromSDCard().execute();
            }
            for (LoadedImage photo : photos) {
                addImage(photo);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add image(s) to the grid view adapter.
     * 
     * @param value
     *            Array of LoadedImages references
     */
    private void addImage(LoadedImage... value) {
        for (LoadedImage image : value) {
            imageAdapter.addPhoto(image);
            imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save bitmap images into a list and return that list.
     * 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()
     */
    @Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        final GridView grid = sdcardImages;
        final int count = grid.getChildCount();
        final LoadedImage[] list = new LoadedImage[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final ImageView v = (ImageView) grid.getChildAt(i);
            list[i] = new LoadedImage(
                    ((BitmapDrawable) v.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
        }

        return list;
    }

    /**
     * Async task for loading the images from the SD card.
     * 
     * @author Mihai Fonoage
     * 
     */
    class LoadImagesFromSDCard extends AsyncTask<Object, LoadedImage, Object> {

        /**
         * Load images from SD Card in the background, and display each image on
         * the screen.
         * 
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
         */
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            // setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            Bitmap newBitmap = null;
            Uri uri = null;

            // Set up an array of the Thumbnail Image ID column we want
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID };
            // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, // Which columns to return
                    null, // Return all rows
                    null, null);
            int columnIndex = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
            int size = cursor.getCount();
            // If size is 0, there are no images on the SD Card.
            if (size == 0) {
                // No Images available, post some message to the user
            }
            int imageID = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                cursor.moveToPosition(i);
                imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
                uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""
                                + imageID);
                try {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                            .openInputStream(uri));
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 500, 500,
                                true);
                        bitmap.recycle();
                        if (newBitmap != null) {
                            publishProgress(new LoadedImage(newBitmap));
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Error fetching image, try to recover
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Add a new LoadedImage in the images grid.
         * 
         * @param value
         *            The image.
         */
        @Override
        public void onProgressUpdate(LoadedImage... value) {
            addImage(value);
        }

        /**
         * Set the visibility of the progress bar to false.
         * 
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adapter for our image files.
     * 
     * @author Mihai Fonoage
     * 
     */
    class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context mContext;
        private ArrayList<LoadedImage> photos = new ArrayList<LoadedImage>();

        public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        public void addPhoto(LoadedImage photo) {
            photos.add(photo);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return photos.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return photos.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photos.get(position).getBitmap());
            return imageView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A LoadedImage contains the Bitmap loaded for the image.
     */
    private static class LoadedImage {
        Bitmap mBitmap;

        LoadedImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
            mBitmap = bitmap;
        }

        public Bitmap getBitmap() {
            return mBitmap;
        }
    }

    /**
     * When an image is clicked, load that image as a puzzle.
     */
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        int columnIndex = 0;
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,
                null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            columnIndex = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            String imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

            FileInputStream is = null;
            BufferedInputStream bis = null;
            try {
                is = new FileInputStream(new File(imagePath));
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                Bitmap useThisBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
                        parent.getWidth(), parent.getHeight(), true);
                bitmap.recycle();
                // Display bitmap (useThisBitmap)
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Try to recover
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (bis != null) {
                        bis.close();
                    }
                    if (is != null) {
                        is.close();
                    }
                    cursor.close();
                    projection = null;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html). Fill it with ImageViews and set the animations as required.

[Edit]

I make no guarantee that this will work without some tweaking but something along these lines should do what you want.

So, first thing, add the view flipper to the xml layout:

```
<ViewFlipper 
    android:id="@+id/image_flipper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ViewFlipper>
```

Get a reference to the view flipper

```
ViewFlipper imageFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById( R.id.image_flipper );
```

Add image views to the flipper

```
for (LoadedImage photo : photos) {//or something like this
    ImageView image = new ImageView ( getApplicationContext() );
    image.setImageBitmap( photo.getBitmap() );
    imageFlipper.addView( image );
}
```

Set the flipper properties and start

```
imageFlipper.setFlipInterval( 5000 ); //5s intervals
imageFlipper.startFlipping();
```

Comment: hi I am new to android development. can you please tell me how to use viewflipper. probably and example. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Edited, wrote it yesterday but lost my connection :-(

Comment: won't that take up an aweful lot of space?

Comment: Potentially, yes, depending on the number, size and quality of the images. The above is simplistic. If you're happy to have a manual slideshow you could hold say 3/5 images in memory and remove/add onFling/onTouch, works quite well. For animated slides it might be possible to handle adding/removing in onAttachedToWindow or start an Asynctask there to load/remove bitmaps, I haven't tried this approach, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [Customizable SlideShow component for the Android Platform](http://code.google.com/p/android-slideshow/). Go to source and fetch download the source code from there, it wil help you a lot in your work.